# WIX write custom log file

Tags: wix

I have a wix project, and i need write custom log file, except msi log.

My idea is as follows:
Write all needed info in one property, and when install complete - write value of property to file in custom action.

I have no idea, how i may increment property value without replacing.

Also, if you have better way to write custom log - i am pleased to read

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you don't want to use the log file that MSI's can inherently log to?

If so, you could just write a custom action and call into the log method...

```
session.Log("This is my custom message.");
```

You could persist your property value in the registry or by using a session property that you expose an Increment() call to, through yet a different custom action.

Comment: Reason is customer :). Now i create many copies of my custom action -  <CustomAction Id="WriteCustomLog%Number%"
    BinaryKey="Bin_WixCopyLogFileCA"
    DllEntry="WriteCustomLog"
    Execute="immediate"
    Return="check" Impersonate="no" />  and call them where needed. But it's not good, i need another solution.